# PYQT Maya QMouseEvent won't work after I wrapInstance it

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, maya

```
from PySide2 import QtGui,QtCore,QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtGui import*
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from shiboken2 import wrapInstance
import maya.OpenMayaUI as mui
import sys
class ui(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super(ui,self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300,500)
        self.mainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow(parent)
        self.setupUI(self.mainWindow)
        self.setFocus()
    def setupUI(self,mainWindow):
        mymainWindow = QWidget(mainWindow)
        mymainWindow.resize(300,500)
    def mousePressEvent(self,e):
        print 'sdfasdf'
        if e.button()==Qt.RightButton:
            print "Clickkkk"
    def Show(self):
        self.mainWindow.show()
class app():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ptr = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
        self.ptr = wrapInstance(long(self.ptr),QtWidgets.QWidget)      
        self.ui = ui(self.ptr)
    def runApp(self):
        self.ui.Show()
        self.ui.setFocus()

tt = app()
tt.runApp()
```

Here is the code I'm testing on. After using `wrapInstance` the `mouseEvent` are no longer working.

But if I didn't wrap it it's work

**not working**

```
class app():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ptr = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
        self.ptr = wrapInstance(long(self.ptr),QtWidgets.QWidget)      
        self.ui = ui(self.ptr)
    def runApp(self):
        self.ui.Show()
        self.ui.setFocus()
```

**working**

I Also change some parent structure in UI class

```
class app():
    def __init__(self):    
        self.ui = ui()
    def runApp(self):
        self.ui.Show()
```

Can anyone explain why the `MouseEvent` won't work after I wrap it? And how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crux of the problem is this: `self.ui.Show()`. This runs your custom method, which in turn runs this `self.mainWindow.show()`. This causes `self.mainWindow` to show, but you subclassed `mousePressEvent` for `ui`, not `self.mainWindow`! So it's not running the event because you're clicking on the wrong widget.

Instead, since `ui` is a `QWidget`, call `self.ui.show()`. You may also have to put `self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window)` in `ui`'s constructor. With this the mouse event runs as expected when the user clicks on it.

Some side notes:

I doubt that you actually want to create a `QMainWindow` in a `QWidget`. It just strikes as odd. Consider sub-classing a `QMainWindow` instead as it should be the 'top' widget.

Also try to avoid importing modules like `from PySide2.QtCore import *`, and import them like this instead `from PySide2 import QtCore`. It's bad practice, pollutes your module's scope, and makes the code much more unreadable/un-maintainable since it's hard to traceback where these variables come from.

Oh, and for the love of god, use some vertical white-spacing :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Green Cell. I understand that the `mousePressEvent` Function are working on the `ui` widget not `self.mainWindow`. But i wonder that why it is work properly without a `wrapInstance` covering on it. And according to your comment i try create the new class for `mainWindow` and put the `mousePressEvent` in it and Boom~!! IT'S WORK!! :). Thank you

Comment: It had nothing to do with `wrapInstance`, and everything to do with showing the wrong widget. If this has resolved your issue please consider accepting it, otherwise edit your question to provide more clarity.